# Take squarish photos with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there an elegant way to only allow the user to take squarish photos with `UIImagePickerController` instead of the default rectangular ones? Something open source, maybe?

Comment: At least you have to search before asking question. Hint : Open picker with edit mode.

Comment: Sure, I did that. And I know that I can get it from UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage. But does not change the view the user sees, does it? They still have to shoot rectangular, right?

Comment: Well, `allowsEditing` indeed did the trick. I wasn't aware that it would let me pick squarish photos. So I didn't even consider using that. Sorry for bothering. If you want, post an answer and I'll accept it, Ashish.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easiest way to do it (without reimplementing UIImagePickerController). First, use an overlay to make the camera field look square. Here's an example for 3.5" screens (you'd need to update it to work for iPhone 5):

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.sourceType = source;

if (source == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
    //Create camera overlay
    CGRect f = imagePickerController.view.bounds;
    f.size.height -= imagePickerController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat barHeight = (f.size.height - f.size.width) / 2;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(f.size);
    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.5] set];
    UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(CGRectMake(0, 0, f.size.width, barHeight), kCGBlendModeNormal);
    UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(CGRectMake(0, f.size.height - barHeight, f.size.width, barHeight), kCGBlendModeNormal);
    UIImage *overlayImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageView *overlayIV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:f];
    overlayIV.image = overlayImage;
    [imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:overlayIV];
}

imagePickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then, after you get a picture back from the `UIImagePickerController`, crop it to a square with something like this:

```
//Crop the image to a square
CGSize imageSize = image.size;
CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
CGFloat height = imageSize.height;
if (width != height) {
    CGFloat newDimension = MIN(width, height);
    CGFloat widthOffset = (width - newDimension) / 2;
    CGFloat heightOffset = (height - newDimension) / 2;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(newDimension, newDimension), NO, 0.);
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-widthOffset, -heightOffset)
                   blendMode:kCGBlendModeCopy
                       alpha:1.];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you plz mark it as answer @ flohei

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That looked like with a bit of work this would've worked as well. What I did instead is just set `allowsEditing` to `true`, as this will display a square to pick from your photo as well.